# Multiple file web uploader that uploads to remote FTP?

Tags: php, ftp, uploader

After tearing my hair out for the last week, I am looking for some sort of web uploader that allows my customers to upload a bunch of files (often up to 200) and store them to a remote FTP server. What I am looking for is something similar to uploadify, swfupload etc. but has the possibility to upload files via my web page (at my hosting company) and stored to my local ftp server.

I am looking for something similar to uploadify, swfupload and such, but it is absolutely critical that it has the possibility to store the files on my local server.

If this is somehow impossible to do, it could also just upload the files to my website via html (which uploadify etc. does) and after completion copy the files from the web server to my local ftp.

The closest thing i found was something called [filechunker](http://encodable.com/filechucker/) and it looked like the perfect solution, BUT it wont let me add multiple files, just one by one.

All help would be greatly apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't give you a concrete answer, but let me say that it should be theoretically possible to do for a Flash or Java application since they can use raw TCP sockets and implement the FTP protocol (but I am not aware of any Flash-based implementation).

If I'm not wrong all major browsers offer native file upload via FTP by browsing to the FTP directory itself (but you can't influence the visual appearance), just like Windows Explorer can access FTP servers and use them like a network drive.

However, I discourage you from using a FTP server at all. That protocol with it's double connection and that passive/non-passive modes often causes problems. It's usually much better to upload via HTTP and implement a HTTP-based file server yourselves, which is rather easy after all (but be very careful not to expose too much of your server's file system).

I see no real reason for using FTP unless you really want to allow your users to use their FTP client of choice, but that is contrary to your question.

Hope this helps.

**Update:** I just noticed the sentence "*copy the files from the web server to my local ftp*". In case you are really talking about two different servers I would still suggest a HTTP upload and then forward the file to the FTP server via the PHP script (your web server acting as a proxy).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's feasible to upload directly from the browser to your FTP as you would have to have your credentials more or less visible on the website (e.g. in your javascript source).

I once created something similar, but because of that issue I decided to upload via `plupload` to Amazon S3 and sync the files afterwards via `s3sync`. The advantages were

- Large filesizes (2GB+)
- One time Tokens for upload, no need to send credentials to the client
- no traffic to your web server (The communication runs `client->s3`)

Take a look at this thread for an implementation: http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=133

Answer (score 0):

After a wild search i finally found something that I could use. [This java applet](http://www.jfileupload.com/products/jfileupload/index.html) lets me upload endless amounts of files, zips them down and i managed to pass a php variable into the applet so the zip file is stored with the users e-mail adress as the filename. Cost me $29 though, but well worth it since I now have full control of where the files go, and who uploadeded them.